# Why this funcional is continuous in $0$ for weak star topology? Corollary of Brezis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I am having difficulty understanding the final part of this corollary 3.15 of Brezis book. I understood the whole construction from the beginning, but I can't see why condition (4) implies the continuity of $\varphi$ at $0$ in the weak star topology. I understand that $W$ is a weak neighborhood of zero, but condition (4) as I understand it only says that in the neighborhood of zero, the values $|\varphi(g)|$ is bounded by a constant. I am wrong? Or $|\alpha - \varphi(f_0)|$ is it getting small?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the way it's written. What happens is that you are free to choose any $f_0\in H^c$. Which allows you to choose $f_0$ with $|\alpha-\varphi(f_0)|$ as small as you want. So, for every $\varepsilon>0$ you find a neighbourhood $W$ of $0$ such that $|\varphi(g)|<\varepsilon$ for all $g\in W$.

Comment: I understood! Thank you for your help.